# Meaning of いやな思い?

Tags: grammar, translation, parsing

So, I was talking to this girl about how I like japan and she asked me that:

> 日本にきていやな思いとか一いつもしなかった？

There are somethings I don't get, first the parsing...

> 日本にきて
>
> いやな思いとか
>
> 一いつもしなかった？

Is my parsing correct?

Now for the meanings I don't get:

> いやな思い Is this the いや that means negative/bad? so a bad feeling or bad thought?
>
> 一いつも I Just don't get why there is a 一 before いつも

My full attempt in translating is

> **Did you have any bad impressions after coming to Japan?**

Even if my attempt is correct, can you help me clear these points?

Thank you!

Comment: `一いつも` -- 「 [一]{ひと}つも」の間違いじゃないですかね・・

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you copy it as it was?

> 日本にきていやな思いとか一いつもしなかった？

The `一` before いつも is a kanji 一【いち】, not a long vowel marker or a dash. You can confirm it by copying it to somewhere else and apply some serif font. While a dash or a long vowel marker can be typed just by pressing <kbd>-</kbd>, the kanji 一 is unlikely to appear by a simple mistype.

So I think she really wanted the kanji 一. I think it's a typo for 一つも【ひとつも】 ("even once"). Maybe she typed `1つも` first, and then tried to correct it to `一つも`.

> 日本にきていやな思いとかひとつもしなかった？
>   So, after coming to Japan, you did not experience bad things even once?

Comment: ohhh that has to be it! Thanks a lot, makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

Are you texting the message with a girl, right? I guess 一 is mystyped with いつも. Parsing aside I don't think that no mistakes in translation. I think 嫌な思いをする means that you have met a thing which makes you feel unpleasant. So, she asked if you had encountered any unpleasant, bad or strange things .

Comment: Yes, it's through instant text messages, so probably a typo then. Why would she use する and not ある? In this case?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira 〜な思いをする means that you have an experience makes you have some feelings. It's a little bit different than just having some feelings. When you met a thing, you felt bad.

Comment: 〜がある is normally used to describe there is something. It's more concrete than to do 〜をする.

Comment: Oh I didn't know 思いをする I thought that you would "have" a thought or feeling. Not "do" it. Can I translate 思いをする as "to have a thought"?

Comment: I believe she mistyped 一つも "not a single" as opposed to いつも. It makes more sense in the context.

Comment: 思いをする you go thorough 思いがある 思いがある means have a strong towards something. This time she asked if you had gone through having a bad feeling. have a thought normally means have an idea. So, it means 考えがある。

Answer (score 2):

> 嫌｛いや｝な思｛おも｝いをする

This is a set phrase whose meaning is explained in other answers.

In this phrase, as you know, 嫌な is an adjective meaning *unpleasant*, 思い is a noun meaning *feelings, emotion, sentiment* or *experience* ​and する means *to feel* or *to experience*.

As for 思い, please look it up in jisho.org [here](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84), then you'll find interesting meanings words related to 思い, also look up 思｛おも｝い出｛で｝　[here](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84%E5%87%BA).

The antonym of the phrase 嫌な思いをする is 良い思いをする. "良い" is normally pronounced as "よい", but it is usually pronounced as "いい" in this phrase.

"日本でいい思いをしてください。 *I hope you will experience pleasant feelings/things in Japan*", and "良い思い出をたくさん作ってください。 *Please make a lot of good memories while staying in Japan*".